# Looking for a space in a column doesn't give the position of the space?

Tags: sql-server

I am using this SELECT:

```
select  romaji, CHARINDEX(Romaji,' ',1) from phrase
```

or this SELECT:

```
select  romaji, CHARINDEX(RTRIM(Romaji),' ',1) from phrase
```

and I get this output with all zeros in the second column always even for the case of morau where there is one one word in the romaji column:

```
ryūgaku             0
tsumaranai          0
aka-i kaban-desu    0
kekkon shite-i-masu 0
morau               0
```

Can anyone give me some advice on what I might be doing wrong?

note that romaji is defined as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Your parameters are the wrong way, it should be charindex (' ', Romaji)

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `CHARINDEX`, the first argument should be the substring which needs to search within the string.

Syntax of *[`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186323.aspx)*

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch , start_location )
```

**Query**

```
select romaji, charindex(' ', rtrim(romaji), 1) from phrase;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if there is a space, I would suggest that you use `case` and `like` instead:

```
select romaji, (case when rtrim(Romaji) like '% %' then 1 else 0 end) as HasSpace
from phrase;
```

Of course, you might actually want the position of the space, in which case `charindex()` is the right choice.